# how long does fiberfix heat wrap last?

Tags: exhaust

I've seen some videos on youtube for using this on exhaust leaks.  Some prominent car repair youtubers seem to endorse this too.

However some amazon reviews seem to say this wont even last beyond a few days.

Anyone have experience with this can I expect it to last a month or longer or do these only last a few days?

Thanks

Comment: If you make all the effort to jack it up you may as well do the job properly... that stuff is a temporary repair otherwise known as a "bodge"...

Answer (score 1):

For exhausts It may work temporarily, but its not a permanent repair. That stuff is best suited to say a mechanically solid exhaust with a small hole etc in a straight section of pipe. However if you have a split exhaust or a loose box/silencer with a sheared weld etc then forget it as you'll be wasting your money.

For a proper exhaust repair only a replacement part or a good welding job to an already structurally sound pipe is the answer.

Comment: I had a sheared pipe on my v8 landrover - temporary repair was a coke can with both ends cut off and two jubilee (hose) clips - got me home without being deafened...

Answer (score 1):

It doesn’t last very long due to the lack of metal stiffness needed to prevent brittle cracking under engine start torque and vibration .

Perhaps it could be improved with sheet metal  wrapped inside the fibreglass/epoxy  wraps to prevent flexing and cracking which quickly increases to gas leaks from hot gas blow thru turbulence.

Thermal expansions may also stress the epoxy.

Answer (score 0):

Try Durafix instead. It’s an alloy that melts a bit below the temperature at which aluminium melts, and far below the melting point of steel and iron. The company has demo videos on youtube; you’ll need a blowtorch (of the cheap variety, at least - I use a Würth torch that cost around 40$) to heat the point that needs fixing.

It is a lot stronger than aluminium, but not as strong as steel. Occasionally it is used to fix cracked engine blocks, though I wouldn’t use it for that. But an exhaust pipe with a leak? No problem. It’s important to scrub away oxidation, even as you heat the exhaust pipe, then you’ll get a perfect bonding with the alloy.

Google durafix, they have local resellers everywhere.